# Override default action of the Options/Preferences button in about:addons

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make my add-ons option button show in the addon manager. But when user clicks it, i want it to `notifyObserver` rather than load the add-ons option page. My goal is: My observer will catch that notify, figure out window, and do stuff in that window. In other case when user clicks it, to open new tab.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is a way, but not a good one, unfortunately. The logic is kinda [hard-coded](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/extensions.js#l1035)

1. Have a stub options dialog (`.xul`) that notifies observers and then closes itself immediately. There will be a short flashing of that dialog, of course.
2. Overlay `about:addons` and `chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul` and hook the [`doCommand`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/extensions.js#l1035) belonging to preferences.
3. Re-bind [`addon-generic`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/extensions.xml#l758), but patching/rebinding this monster of a binding is not only not easy but also very fragile (may get out of sync if future Firefox changes something) and also not even enough because there is still [a menu item](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/extensions.xul#l58) in the context menu.

So in conclusion: Either be OK with 1. or don't do this at all (because the gain does not nearly outweigh the fuss).

You could also add just a new button. E.g. in [Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/find/master/) I added some new buttons by re-binding `.control-container`. See `addonstab.*`.

Comment: Thanks so much. The way I was doing it right now was real sloppy. I would listen on browser for load of 'about:addons' then I would get access to `wrappedJSObejct` then I would check `gViewController.viewId == 'addons://list/extension'` if it is then I would iterate through find my add-on and find the options button then hack it up to not do default command tand notify. I also would addEventListener `gViewController.viewPort.addEventListener('ViewChanged', extViewLoaded, false)` for future loads in that addon:manager tab if they ever come back to the page.

Comment: That sounds... nasty LOL And also missing the menu item.

Comment: hahaha! i know man i work hard but drive myself crayzOh my gosh you just gave me super idea! What do you think of rather than overriding the bind, appending the bind, making a new button and new menu item show that just mimics appearce, so buttons reads "Options"? And of course just target our addons richlist item with css type=id or something like that. Ill give this a shot!

Comment: Yeah, this could work. Totally missed that opportunity. And I even did something like this for Scriptish a while back (adding Edit and Open Folder buttons). See the `addonstab.*` stuff, where control-container is rebound to add the buttons.

Comment: I know that XUL is going away soon, but I'm still maintaining an add-on and learning XUL. This is an old itch time that I decided to try to scratch today. My needs and solution are simpler. All I want is to silently add an argument to pass window, so dialog can see parent window. I observe `chrome-document-global-created` for `subject.location == about:addons`, but then I got stuck trying to find gViewController. From the console, I have a simple regex `/(openDialog\([^\)]+)\);\s*$/gm;` to replace with `"$1, {'__window_parent':window});"` on `gViewController.commands.cmd_showItemPreferences`.